# multiple table inner join didn't get expected values

Tags: mysql

Student_register table:

```
regNo 
pro(HNDIT,HNDA,HNDFT)
name
start_day
etc ... more columns
```

Semester:

```
regNo
curSemmester(3,4,5)
name
```

The query I used to get values:

```
SELECT student_register.pro='HNDIT', student_register.regNo,sem.curSem =4,sem.name
FROM student_register
INNER JOIN sem
ON sem.regNo = student_register.regNo
ORDER BY sem.regNo;
```

I need to get `regNo` from `student_register` that according to pro = hndit or any other (hndft/HNDA) then I want to compare those `regNo` to current semester which that user define curSem=3 (4/5/6) regNo Numbers

Get student numbers who do HNDIT course and then get regNO from semester table that user define semester(3 or 4 or 5 ) student who do Course hndit:

```
student_register.pro='HNDIT' -> sem.curSem =4 -> regNo and name
```

Comment: kindly edit the question for better understanding

Comment: what are the unclear areas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that you want sem3 then query will be

**Case 1#**

```
Select stureg.regno,stureg.pro,stureg.name,stureg.start_day,
sem.regno,sem.curSemmester,sem.name
from student_register as stureg left outer join semester as sem on stureg.regno=sem.regno
where stureg.pro REGEXP '^H' and sem.CurSemmester='3'

group by regno

order by regno
;
```

**Case 2#**

```
Select stureg.regno,stureg.pro,stureg.name,stureg.start_day,
sem.regno,sem.curSemmester,sem.name
from student_register as stureg left outer join semester as sem on stureg.regno=sem.regno
where stureg.pro like '%H%' and sem.CurSemmester='3'

group by regno

order by regno
;
```

Give it Try.

Comment: this work fine and thank you but their are  little problem here i get resultset that with repeated columns like regNo and name how to avoid those and get only name and regNo thank you again for your help